# Tiny OS timer not resetting

Tags: timer, tinyos, nesc

I'am currently working on tinyos and I Am trying to reset timer 
lets say to 2 seconds when it is running at 45 seconds 
but it is not working, i can't figure out why,

can someone help me figure it out

here is the code:

```
printf("timer before resetting it %ld",call Timer1.getNow());
offset = ((TimeMote_t*) payload)->tdata;
call Timer1.startPeriodic(offset);
printf("timer after resetting it %ld",call Timer1.getNow());
```

now actually it should have reset the timer to offset but it's not resetting it.
both printf statements are giving the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it shouldn't. `Timer.getNow()` returns absolute time, which can't be changed or reset. `Timer` interface can be used to schedule events at a particular moment in the future. `Timer.startPeriodic(offset)` starts the timer, meaning that the event `Timer.fired()` will be signaled in the future. In this particular example, the event will be signaled `offset` units from the call to `Timer.startPeriodic` and then repeated every `offset` units infinitely or until call to `Timer.stop()`. Return value of `Timer.getNow()` doesn't change and increases monotonically regardless of whether the timer is started or not.

See: [Interface: tos.lib.timer.Timer](http://www.tinyos.net/tinyos-2.1.0/doc/nesdoc/mica2/ihtml/tos.lib.timer.Timer.html)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know
Finall. I got the workaround for it i store the old timer and subtract it from current time so display time so that it only shows the offset value.